# Почему у меня возникает ошибка при запуске телеграм бота

Tags: python-3.x

Код ошибки:

```
/home/omega/Рабочий стол/#Code/Python/Telegrame_Bot_SATI/Sati.py:30: TelegramDeprecationWarning: Old Handler API is deprecated - see https://git.io/fxJuV for details
  bot = bot,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omega/Рабочий стол/#Code/Python/Telegrame_Bot_SATI/Sati.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/omega/Рабочий стол/#Code/Python/Telegrame_Bot_SATI/Sati.py", line 34, in main
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(handler)
NameError: name 'updater' is not defined
```

Часть где возникает ошибка:

```
def main():
    bot = Bot(
        token = TG_TOKEN,
    )
    update = Updater(
        bot = bot,
    )

    handler = MessageHandler(Filters.all, message_handler)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Вот весь код

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters

TG_TOKEN = "1000229483:AAE4UzZeIgc1NSuN16u1I9wp5j4ZRQoJwEc"

def message_handler(bot: Bot, update: Update):
    user = update.effective_user
    if user: 
        neme= user.first_name
    else:
        name = "Аноним"

    text = update.effective_message.text
    reply_text = f"Привет, {name}!\n\n{text}"

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id = update.effective_message.chat_id,
        text = reply_text,
    )


def main():
    bot = Bot(
        token = TG_TOKEN,
    )
    update = Updater(
        bot = bot,
    )

    handler = MessageHandler(Filters.all, message_handler)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: В ошибке прямо написано, в чём проблема.

Comment: Хорошо имя не определено

Comment: Но в чем ошибка может я что-то не так написал в импорте или что еще

Comment: Попробуйте отладить Вашу программу в дебаггере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправь

```
update = Updater
```

на

```
updater = Updater
```

Answer (score 0):

Дописать строчку

```
bot = bot, use_context=True
```

Чтоб было так

```
updater = Updater(
    bot = bot, use_context=True
)
```